# Como ler Arquivos de Remessa de Boletos que são enviados aos Bancos?

Tags: java, boleto

Gostaria de saber uma forma eficaz e estruturada para ler os Arquivos de Remessa de Boletos que são enviados aos Bancos. Já encontrei algumas bibliotecas que geram esses arquivos, mas nenhuma que leia esses arquivos.

Se ao menos existir uma biblioteca simples que já contém a estrutura lógica da CNAB, eu poderia continuar.

Sendo mais específico, eu preciso ler os arquivos que seguem esse layout do Itaú (http://download.itau.com.br/bankline/layout_cobranca_400bytes_cnab_itau.pdf) e do Bradesco (http://www.bradesco.com.br/portal/PDF/pessoajuridica/solucoes-integradas/outros/layout-de-arquivo/cobranca/4008-524-0121-08-layout-cobranca-versao-portugues.pdf)

Estou começando a conhecer a poderosa biblioteca jabuticava, mas é dificil entender quais os Objetos ou Transfer Objects que devo utilizar caso não exista um método fácil para isso e caso eu mesmo desenvolva a leitura dos arquivos.

Comment: Tu podes usar [essa biblioteca](http://www.jrimum.org/bopepo/). Eu nunca usei, mas já ouvi falar muito bem dela. E, ao invés de desenvolver do zero e sozinho, tu podes contribuir com o projeto.

Comment: Você precisa ler o arquivo de remessa com os dados dos boletos? Se é isso basta utilizar alguma biblioteca que leia arquivos .txt que consegue resolver isso. Já se o que quer é gerar o boleto sua pergunta está incorreta.

Comment: Esta biblioteca gera o boleto apenas ou le arquivos de remessa?

Comment: @GiovaniRaciPaganini, Faz os dois.

Comment: Não conhecia ela, bem bacana :D